# Why am I getting segmentation fault/how do I overload an operator?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

This is a problem on HackerRank (Introduction C++). I am given main(). I am trying to write a class for a matrix which is represented by a vector>. I need to overload + to make it add my matrix objects. The tests will input four lines: first line will say how many tests cases to expect, second line will specify dimensions (first number is rows, second number is columns), third line will give the first matrix (first m numbers, separated by spaces, will go in the first row... then the next m numbers will go into the second row...etc.), and fourth line will give the second matrix.

When I run the first test case, I get a segmentation fault. When I eliminated the int declarations and the for loops in my operator definition, and simply had it return matrixprime, I obviously got the wrong answer for the matrix addition, but it at least output without an error. 
Before, in order to access the elements of the matrix, I used "matrix.a.at(i).at(j)" instead of "matrix.a[i][j]" and got an out_of_range error for the vector. I feel like these issues are related somehow to my temporary matrix object (if that's the right thing to call it) in my operator definition, but don't understand what is going wrong exactly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
enter code here

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:
vector<vector<int>> a;
Matrix operator+ (const Matrix&);
};

Matrix Matrix::operator+ (const Matrix& matrixprime) {
    Matrix matrix;
    int n = matrix.a.size(); 
    int m = matrix.a[0].size();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            matrix.a[i][j] = matrix.a[i][j] + matrixprime.a[i][j];  
        };
    };
    return matrix;  
};

int main () {
   int cases,k;
   cin >> cases;
   for(k=0;k<cases;k++) {
  Matrix x;
  Matrix y;
  Matrix result;
  int n,m,i,j;
  cin >> n >> m;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
     vector<int> b;
     int num;
     for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
        cin >> num;
        b.push_back(num);
     }
     x.a.push_back(b);
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
     vector<int> b;
     int num;
     for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
        cin >> num;
        b.push_back(num);
     }
     y.a.push_back(b);
  }
  result = x+y;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
     for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
        cout << result.a[i][j] << " ";
     }
     cout << endl;
  }
}  
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
Matrix matrix;
```

the compiler uses the default constructor created by the compiler. It initializes the member `a` using its default constructor, which is an empty vector.

You need to create a vector with the right number of elements before you can us `at()` or `oprator[]` on it.

With an empty vector, the line

```
int m = matrix.a[0].size();
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

You need something along the lines of:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+ (const Matrix& matrixprime)
{
   // Initialize the matrix to be returned to be the same
   // as the LHS of the operator.
   Matrix matrix;
   matrix.a = this->a;

   // Now increment the elements of the matrix to be returned
   // by the elements of the RHS of the operator.
   int n = matrix.a.size(); 
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      int m = matrix.a[i].size();
      for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
      {
         matrix.a[i][j] += matrixprime.a[i][j];  
      }
   }

   return matrix;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I got it to work, I have seen the "this" operator quite a lot, but don't really understand how it works. For starts, the idea of pointers is a little new to me. But also, would you mind explaining the syntax used with "this"? What is the compiler doing as it reads "this"?

Comment: @Yang-YangFeng, Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this. Hopefully it answers your questions about `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that on your plus operator overloaping function the `matrix` var is uninitialized, and the other hand you should use something like this `matrix.a[i][j] = this->a[i][j] + matrixprime.a[i][j];`

Comment: with this little change on your code, I think that is sufficient for a working code ;) best regards